# Jmeter problem with http request

Tags: jmeter

I have to make two http requests. The first request generates an xml variable whose value is an integer. Now I have to make a second http request and I must use the first request integer value in part of the second http request path(url)?

Is this possible?

Comment: Also read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455332/possible-to-store-result-from-jmeter-request-and-use-it

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [Post-processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) in your first request and extract the Integer value from the response using either **Regular Expression Extractor** or [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor), once this value is extracted and stored in a variable as per extractor syntax, use this variable in your next HTTP request URL (path) and this will pass the required value, making your script working as required.

Refer below links for step-by-step guide of using Post-Processor in JMeter

https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1743642-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jmeter

https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0